# Console Application drag and drop "C#"

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

I was loading an MS Word file programmatically using Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll.

When the Word file is opened, I want to disable drag and drop facility for it.

How do I do that? Is it possible to achieve this in user32.dll?

Comment: Drag and drop what?  I think you need to provide more details to get a good answer.

Comment: What does this have to do with console applications? Don't console apps by definition not have drag&drop?

Comment: I think the OP might be invoking Word *from* a console app, and wants the instance of Word to have drag-n-drop disabled. Maybe? Either way, I suspect this question is either incoherent or the answer is "no". :S

Comment: I think he wants to avoid drag & drop functionality between two word documents. Put some sample code to get better answer.

Comment: i was opened word document programmatically in that i was mentioned drag and drop fecilty false.

the word document was opened fine and i selected all information and drag and drop it into another document means the information will be pasted into another document.
but actually my pro-grammatically opened document will not have the option for drag and drop. so it will not be happen (ie drag and drop).

so how to avoid this.

need ur suggetsions with examples

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for

```
Application.Options.AllowDragAndDrop = false;
```

[Application.Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.options%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

[Options class members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.options_members%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

I'm not sure if any options you change persist or not when the application is closed, but I would make sure you revert any options changes you do when you application closes or in case of an unexpected termination.